# sed regex cannot get first match

Tags: regex, sed

I give up... of the following

```
15 Sep 1605.00 (SPX1530U1605-E),0.25,0.0,0.05,0.10,0,87
```

I want to extract the number 1530 out of the blob. "SPX" can be any combination of capital letters [A-Z] and varies in length, (e.g. GOOG, FB). There is always a capital letter following the number, as in "U" in the example.

Below gets the second number, 1605. I'm at loss on how to extract 1530.

```
echo "15 Sep 1605.00 (SPX1530U1605-E),0.0,0.0,266.10,284.60,0,0" | \
gsed -r 's/.*[A-Z]([0-9].*)[-][A-Z].*/\1/g'
```

It would be acceptable to perform the operation on just the string "SPXW1530I1605-E" rather than the entire line.

Comment: your regex don't match your definition; ***There is always a capital letter following the number***: your regex could be: `[A-Z]([0-9].*)[A-Z].*` (no `[-]`!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `grep` is the tool of choice when you only want to extract data. You can use GNU grep, it offers perl compatile regular expression when you pass the `-P` option:

```
grep -oP '\([A-Z]+\K[0-9]+' file
```

We are searching for a literal `(` followed by 1 or more capital (ASCII) letters. Then we are using `\K` which cleans up the match buffer. (Nice, isn't it?) The following numbers are the final match.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
s='15 Sep 1605.00 (SPX1530U1605-E),0.25,0.0,0.05,0.10,0,87'
sed -r 's/.*[A-Z]+([0-9]+)[A-Z].*/\1/' <<< "$s"
1530
```

Comment: Plus 1 because this is more portable than using `grep -oP` like I've suggested.

Comment: It might be more portable but `grep` with `\K` is more elegant +1